# Problems with Characterset when using DB2 SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD for database import

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I am running a Java Application that transfers the files I need to import to the server the DB2 is on. Then the Java Application creates a JDBC Connection to the database and runs:

```
 CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('import from <filename> of del modified by decpt, coldel; messages on server inert into <view>')
```

The problem I have seems somehow conencted to the charset of either the database of the user the database uses to import the files (using the admin_cmd stored procedure). That problem is:
"Umlaute", like ä,ö,ü get messed up by this import. I had this sort of problem in the past and solution always was to set the LC_CTYPE of the user importing the data to de_DE.iso88591

What I already ruled out as the source of the problem:
- The file transfer to the database server. (Umlaute are still ok after that)
- The JDBC Connection (I simply inserted a line through the sql command instead of reading from a file)

The thing is I don't now what user DB2 uses to import files through ADMIN_CMD. And I also don't believe it could somehow be connected to the DB2 settings, since with every other way of inserting,loading ... data into it, everthing works fine.

And yes, I need to use ADMIN_CMD. The DB2 Command Line Tool is a performance nightmare ..

Answer (score 0):

The best approach (for sanity):

1. Create all databases as UTF-8
2. Make sure all operating system locales are UTF-8
3. Get rid of all applications that don't handle their data as UTF-8
4. Slaughter every developer and vendor not adhering to UTF-8. Repeat and rinse until 100% completed.

DB2 indeed [attempts to be smart](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506chong/) and convert your input data for you (the import command basically pipes your data into insert clauses - which always get handled like that). The link I gave will outline the basic principle, and give you a few commands to try out. Also, there is [official explanation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0005433.htm) to the similar. According it you could attempt setting the environment variable **db2codepage** to correspond with your delimited data files, and that should help. Also, the IXF format exports might work better since they have encoding related information attached in every file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

I finally fixed the issue by adding a

```
MODIFIED BY CODEPAGE=1252
```

to my JDBC - ADMIN_CMD Import Command. This seems to override any codepage settings the db was using before. It also appears the default codepage of the database didn't matter, since it is set to 1252. The only thing I can think of right now for being the reason for all this could be a linux setting DB2 uses when importing through ADMIN_CMD.